# Google Sheets Coding by column NAME not letter/number?

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets :

Is it possible to code a cell in a sheet to pull in information from another cell in another sheet, inside the same workbook, by the title of the column that I give it, instead of using something like :

=Sheet1!A2

so that it looks for the Column Header Text to bring in the info no matter where it is in Sheet 1? 
I have csv files that vary with some columns, the most important columns, so they won't always be at the same LetterNumber location.

Comment: I am looking at a =VLOOKUP+MATCH coding that works in Excel but I can't even get that to work correctly. At this point I would rather do it in Excel if anyone has a way because not doing it is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

[OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) in conjunction with MATCH might suit.

```
=offset(Sheet1!A1,1,match("name1",Sheet1!1:1,0)-1)
```

A formula such as above should return a value from Row2 (`1` lower/higher number than the row of the reference cell `A1`) of Sheet1 from the column defined by the match function. `name1` (a column label) might be anywhere in the first row of Sheet1.

Comment: I'm getting #NAME? 
The column name: 4 of 2 Wedding Gondola (R)
so I have :
 =offset(Sheet1!A1;1;match("4 of 2 Wedding Gondola (R)";Sheet1!1:1;0)-1)